# Jquery ajax response from server extract

Tags: jquery, ajax

How to extract response from server in jquery ajax...along this a put my code, here a want to do like this. using the user name and password "login_check.php" check the database and echo the value "login successful" or invalid username and password or something other like that.But when i alert the response from "login_check.php" showing html contents like that.. i want to check only the response and depending on the do something like redirect or show error message .. How i can do..? if any one help, this is very useful to me...

Thanks

Rob

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
      $("#form").submit(function(event){
         var uname=document.getElementById('uname').value;
         var userpass=document.getElementById('userpass').value;

         $.post("login_check.php", 
           { 
              username:uname,
              password:userpass,
           },
           function(response,status){
             if(status=='success') {
              var res=document.getElementById('resmessage').innerHTML=response;
              alert(response);      
            }
         });
         return false;
      });
   });
</script>
```

Comment: pls check your script, I think this is not correct, 
var res=document.getElementById('resmessage').innerHTML=response;
alert(response);

Comment: Are you trying to avoid having HTML in your response ?

Comment: var res=document.getElementById('resmessage').innerHTML=response; here i can put the response to inner HTML .. actually i want check the response from server and depend on the value , i want to do some other operation..@Valath

Comment: Yes avoid HTML is better from server...any other solutions? @Su4p

Comment: this is it you simply avoid HTML being outputed from server. One way to put it if you don't want to change your code is : in your javascript you change the url login_check.php by login_check.php?ajax_mode=on. And in your PHP file you can do SLT if(isset($_GET['ajax_mode'])){ echo 'just the response'}else{/*old code*/ }

Comment: Nothing happened by change url  login_check.php?ajax_mode=on instead  of login_check.php and i checked "if(isset($_GET['ajax_mode'])) " in php file @Su4p

Answer (score 0):

In your login_check.php you should echo
 "Success login" if the login is ok else: "invalid username,password".

The response in your ajax will return the echo message from login_check.php

Comment: I already echo the message like you mentioned . but i want to check which echo value is responded by ajax .i alert the the response in java script . but it contains HTML elements...So how can check the response...?

Comment: Why there are HTML elements? The message you echo in your login_check.php contain HTML elements?

Comment: Give us your login_check.php

Comment: @ Christos , this is my login_check file
<?php 
   include('db.php');
   $uname=$_POST['username'];
   $upass=$_POST['password'];
   $sel="select * from signup where u_name='$uname' and p_word='$upass'";
   $selqry=mysql_query($sel);
   $num=mysql_num_rows($selqry);   
   if(isset($_GET['ajax_mode'])) 
   { 
 if($num==1)
   {
  echo "Valid Username & Password";
   }
   if($num==0)
   {
    echo "Invalid username & Password";
   }
   if($num>1)
   {
    echo "Sorry ! You can't login. Please contact us..";
   }
     }
   else
   {
   } 
     
 ?>

Comment: depending on the number of rows, i want to send the different message echoing in the login_check.php page to login.php page as response and i want to check this message . depending this message do some action..example redirect or like that...

Comment: No i mean, lets say you make a valid login, $num==1 so the message should be: Valid Username & Password, but in your alert? what do you get? (with HTML elements)

Comment: Actually i want to redirect to another page or show error message in login.php (innerHTML) page depending 
on the fetch data in login_check.php page . I can show error message in innerHTMl in login.php
But if ($num==1), i want to redirect to another page.
if($num==1)
   {
 header("Location:home.php")
  
   }
the above mentioned "header("Location:home.php")" is not working . This also show in innerHTML.

Firstly i tried to check the response from server. this is not possible .because the response contains HTML
elements.Thats why i used alert(response) to see response

Comment: Are you try to redirect from jquery? if the message is "ok" redirect ? sorry may i dont understand exactly your problem

Comment: I have two files one is login.php and other is login_check.php. above i mentioned jquery code of login.php. when i enter username and password in login.php page, it will goes to login_check.php page and select the data from database and it will check. if($num==0), echo "Invalid username & Password"; and it will show in innerHTML tag in login.php page. if($num>1)  echo "Sorry ! You can't login. Please contact us.."; and it will also show in innerHTML tag in login.php page.

Comment: But if($num==1) i don't want to echo , i want to redirect to another page... I don't to how to do...This is my problem . I tried header("Location:home.php"). but it also shown in innerHTML tag.. How can I redirect....?

Comment: Ok let the response from php file as it is( a simple message, ok or not ok).
Then in your jquery, if response is OK use: window.location.href="http:/www.thePagetoRedirect.com" for redirecting